# How to put html data in variables or array using jquery to send to new page for use

Tags: jquery, html

If i have the following html

```
<div id="title">
    <h1>Games</h1>
</div>
<div id="games">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Stars</td><td>Texas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hoggs</td><td>Kansas</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Using Jquery, how would i take the contents inside the div title and games, put them in there own variable and send the data to another page for use. So...

```
var title = '<h1>Games</h1>';
var games = '<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Stars</td><td>Texas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hoggs</td><td>Kansas</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
```

i want to take those 2 varibles and sent to new page via button. Im guess I could use the .ajax function in jquery

Comment: There is too much that you want to do for a single question. Please re-phrase your question to be more specific and if you have multiple questions, create multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send your variable to another page using [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you would need to do as such:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    var data = {
        title: $('#title').html(),
        games: $('#games').html()
    };

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourpage.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(returnValue) {
            // do whatever is needed with returnValue
        }
    });
});
```

If you include this HTML:

```
<button>Send data to server</button>
```

You can then retrieve your values in **yourpage.php**:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    var_dump($_POST['title']);
    var_dump($_POST['games']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting your form, then just create two hidden input in the form and assign then with the value from the two variable, then once post back you will see the value. Such as:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
   $("#hidInput1").val(title);
   $("#hidInput2").val(games);

   return true;
})
```